# Selecting most recent record in large query based on one value in SELECT field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

I have a large query, well relatively large.  This query constantly produces multiple results on the MATERIAL column even though I have specified 'DISTINCT'.  I thought by specifying 'DISTINCT' and summing the values I needed that it would produce one line per MATERIAL number.  Can anybody help me see what I am doing wrong here.  I realize the last sub query might be redundant at this point - I was testing and this is what was producing the result I was getting.

Thanks ahead of time.

```
DECLARE @daynumber as int
SET     @daynumber = CASE
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Monday'
                  THEN 56
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday' 
                  THEN 57
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Wednesday' 
                  THEN 58
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Thursday' 
                  THEN 59
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Friday' 
                  THEN 60
                  END;

SELECT          DISTINCT MATERIAL,
                PLANT_CODE,
                STOCK_CATEGORY,
                material_desc AS 'MATERIAL_DESC',
                division_id AS 'DIVISION_ID',
                UPPER(division_desc) AS 'DIVISION_DESC',
                UPPER(gender_id) AS 'GENDER_ID',
                UPPER(gender_desc) AS 'GENDER_DESC',
                DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                PERIOD_CODE,
                REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                SIZE_LITERAL,
                [ORIGINAL FCST QTY],
                WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                [REM PLAN QTY],
                FUTURE_FCST,
                TOTAL_OH_INV
FROM (

SELECT          P1.PLANT_CODE,
                P1.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P1.MATERIAL,
                M1.material_desc AS 'MATERIAL_DESC',
                M1.division_id AS 'DIVISION_ID',
                UPPER(M1.division_desc) AS 'DIVISION_DESC',
                UPPER(M1.gender_id) AS 'GENDER_ID',
                UPPER(M1.gender_desc) AS 'GENDER_DESC',
                P1.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P1.PERIOD_CODE,
                P1.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P1.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P1.[ORIGINAL FCST QTY],
                P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P1.[REM PLAN QTY],
                P2.FUTURE_FCST,
                SUM(I1.ON_HAND_QUANTITY) AS 'TOTAL_OH_INV'
FROM

(SELECT         PLANT_CODE,
                STOCK_CATEGORY,
                MATERIAL,
                DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                PERIOD_CODE,
                REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                PLANNED_QTY AS 'REM PLAN QTY',
                VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                SIZE_LITERAL,
                WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                PLANNED_QTY + WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS 'ORIGINAL FCST QTY'
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT 
 WHERE          PLANT_CODE IN ('6040','6041')
 AND            STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 AND            DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00','01','ZU','Z2')
 AND            REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - @daynumber
 AND            PLANNED_QTY > 0) AS P1

 LEFT OUTER JOIN      

 (SELECT
                SUM(PLANNED_QTY) AS 'FUTURE_FCST',
                MATERIAL,
                TECHNICAL_INDEX
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          REQUIREMENTS_DATE >= GETDATE()
 AND            PLANNED_QTY > 0
 AND            STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 GROUP BY       MATERIAL,
                TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                SIZE_LITERAL) AS P2
 ON             P1.MATERIAL = P2.MATERIAL
 AND            P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = P2.TECHNICAL_INDEX

 LEFT OUTER JOIN 

 (SELECT        ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
                TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                MATERIAL,
                STOCK_CATEGORY,
                PLANT_CODE
  FROM          VW_INVENTORY I
  WHERE         STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
  GROUP BY      TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                MATERIAL,
                STOCK_CATEGORY,
                ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
                PLANT_CODE) AS I1
  ON            P1.MATERIAL = I1.MATERIAL
  AND           P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = I1.TECHNICAL_INDEX
  AND           P1.PLANT_CODE = I1.PLANT_CODE

  LEFT OUTER JOIN

 (SELECT        M.material_number, 
                M.material_desc,
                M.division_id,
                D.division_desc,
                M.gender_id,
                G.gender_desc
FROM            MaterialMaster.dbo.Material M

JOIN            MaterialMaster.dbo.Ref_Division D
ON              M.division_id = D.division_id
JOIN            MaterialMaster.dbo.Ref_Gender G
ON              M.gender_id = G.gender_id) AS M1

ON              P1.MATERIAL = M1.material_number


GROUP BY        P1.PLANT_CODE,
                P1.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P1.MATERIAL,
                P1.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P1.PERIOD_CODE,
                P1.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P1.[REM PLAN QTY],
                P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P1.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P1.[ORIGINAL FCST QTY],
                P2.FUTURE_FCST,
                M1.material_desc,
                M1.division_id,
                M1.division_desc,
                M1.gender_id,
                M1.gender_desc) AS T1 /* T1 Represents "Total" for all */

GROUP BY        PLANT_CODE,
                STOCK_CATEGORY,
                MATERIAL,
                material_desc,
                division_id,
                division_desc,
                gender_id,
                gender_desc,
                DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                PERIOD_CODE,
                REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                SIZE_LITERAL,
                [ORIGINAL FCST QTY],
                WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                [REM PLAN QTY],
                FUTURE_FCST,
                TOTAL_OH_INV
```

Comment: I have a rule of thumb. If I have to use "select distinct", I've done something wrong or at least I could do it better. [This article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2008/11/11/60752.aspx) explains it well.

Comment: There simply is - never - a need to include `distinct` in a single query already using `group by`; it is just redundant. @mason I like that article also

Comment: `select distinct` produces **rows** that are unique, the **whole row** is considered. So, if you have used select distinct, and you still think the information isn't "distinct" then you just haven't used the right technique. BUT: without you demonstrating through some data what your problem really is we could be guessing for a long time; but often row_number() solves situations like this. You really need to supply sample data and expected result (or better setup a sqlfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You use 2 times `GROUP BY` clause that does the same thing. The outer `GROUP BY` has no effect.  Moreover using `DISTINCT` when you have already used `GROUP BY` means, that somethig is wrong, as @mason pointed out in his comment. You have tried to remove some rows but it is not a good way to go, it only obfuscates the problem.

Another recommendation: for field names use `[` and `]` chars instead of `'` chars, e.g. `M1.material_desc AS [MATERIAL_DESC]`. It will improve readability of your SQL which is something you need badly writing longer queries - char literals are in red.

So the inner query - the problematic part - should be reformatted like this to be readable:

```
SELECT  P1.PLANT_CODE, P1.STOCK_CATEGORY, P1.MATERIAL, M1.material_desc AS [MATERIAL_DESC], M1.division_id AS [DIVISION_ID], 
        UPPER(M1.division_desc) AS [DIVISION_DESC], UPPER(M1.gender_id) AS [GENDER_ID], UPPER(M1.gender_desc) AS [GENDER_DESC], 
        P1.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE, P1.PERIOD_CODE, P1.REQUIREMENTS_DATE, P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG, P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX, P1.SIZE_LITERAL, 
        P1.[ORIGINAL FCST QTY], P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY, P1.[REM PLAN QTY], P2.[FUTURE_FCST], SUM(I1.ON_HAND_QUANTITY) 
        AS [TOTAL_OH_INV]
        FROM (SELECT PLANT_CODE, STOCK_CATEGORY, MATERIAL, DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE, PERIOD_CODE, REQUIREMENTS_DATE, 
                     PLANNED_QTY AS [REM PLAN QTY], VERSION_IND_FLAG, SIZE_LITERAL, WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY, TECHNICAL_INDEX, 
                     PLANNED_QTY + WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS [ORIGINAL FCST QTY]
               FROM  VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT
               WHERE (PLANT_CODE IN ('6040', '6041')) AND (STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000', 'A60385003')) 
                      AND (DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00', '01', 'ZU', 'Z2')) 
                      AND (REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - @daynumber) AND (PLANNED_QTY > 0)
        ) AS P1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (SELECT  SUM(PLANNED_QTY) AS [FUTURE_FCST], MATERIAL, TECHNICAL_INDEX
                     FROM    VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT AS P
                     WHERE   (REQUIREMENTS_DATE >= GETDATE()) AND (PLANNED_QTY > 0) 
                             AND (STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000', 'A60385003'))
                     GROUP BY MATERIAL, TECHNICAL_INDEX, SIZE_LITERAL 
        ) AS P2 ON P1.MATERIAL = P2.MATERIAL AND P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = P2.TECHNICAL_INDEX 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (SELECT  ON_HAND_QUANTITY, TECHNICAL_INDEX, MATERIAL, STOCK_CATEGORY, PLANT_CODE
                     FROM    VW_INVENTORY AS I
                     WHERE   (STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000', 'A60385003'))
                     GROUP BY TECHNICAL_INDEX, MATERIAL, STOCK_CATEGORY, ON_HAND_QUANTITY, PLANT_CODE 
        ) AS I1 ON P1.MATERIAL = I1.MATERIAL AND P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = I1.TECHNICAL_INDEX AND P1.PLANT_CODE = I1.PLANT_CODE 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
               (SELECT   M.material_number, M.material_desc, M.division_id, D.division_desc, M.gender_id, G.gender_desc
                FROM     MaterialMaster.dbo.Material AS M 
                INNER JOIN MaterialMaster.dbo.Ref_Division AS D ON M.division_id = D.division_id 
                INNER JOIN MaterialMaster.dbo.Ref_Gender AS G ON M.gender_id = G.gender_id
        ) AS M1 ON P1.MATERIAL = M1.material_number
GROUP BY PLANT_CODE, STOCK_CATEGORY, MATERIAL, DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE, PERIOD_CODE, REQUIREMENTS_DATE, 
        P1.[REM PLAN QTY], P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG, P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY, P1.SIZE_LITERAL, P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX, P1.[ORIGINAL FCST QTY], 
        P2.[FUTURE_FCST], M1.material_desc, M1.division_id, M1.division_desc, M1.gender_id, M1.gender_desc
```

Here you should look for your problem.

Check every inner SELECT separately a verify if it is returning desired results. The problem could be that you have twice SELECT from VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT. I suggest that you try to remove P2 subquery and see what happens. Why P2 is not a part of P1 subquery?

```
        FROM (SELECT PLANT_CODE, STOCK_CATEGORY, MATERIAL, DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE, PERIOD_CODE, REQUIREMENTS_DATE, 
                     PLANNED_QTY AS [REM PLAN QTY], VERSION_IND_FLAG, SIZE_LITERAL, WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY, TECHNICAL_INDEX, 
                     PLANNED_QTY + WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS [ORIGINAL FCST QTY]
                     (SELECT SUM(PLANNED_QTY) 
                     FROM    VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT 
                     WHERE   (REQUIREMENTS_DATE >= GETDATE()) AND (PLANNED_QTY > 0) 
                             AND (STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000', 'A60385003'))
                             AND MATERIAL=P.MATERIAL AND TECHNICAL_INDEX=P.TECHNICAL_INDEX
                     GROUP BY SIZE_LITERAL) AS [FUTURE_FCST]
               FROM  VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
               WHERE (PLANT_CODE IN ('6040', '6041')) AND (STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000', 'A60385003')) 
                      AND (DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00', '01', 'ZU', 'Z2')) 
                      AND (REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - @daynumber) AND (PLANNED_QTY > 0)
        ) AS P1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (SELECT  ON_HAND_QUANTITY, TECHNICAL_INDEX, MATERIAL, STOCK_CATEGORY, PLANT_CODE
```

Also LEFT OUTER JOIN can produce rows without any MATERIAL. Why not INNER JOIN?

But your problem cannot be solved miraculously in the final GROUP BY clause, because there you only SUM one field of all selected fields.